# Web API parameter bind dynamically built table values to model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, parameters, model

Imagine you were creating an online test application.  It lets you add multiple choice test questions.  So the user clicks "Add new test question" and a dialog comes up.  The dialog asks for the question text, a list of possible answers, and the correct answer.  So something like this would be the result:

```
    Which color has the letter "G" in it?
            A.  Blue
            B.  Red
    ---->   C.  Green
            D.  Yellow
            E.  Purple
```

Each new question would likely have different number of options.  So the next question might be:

```
    Does NYC have 5 boroughs?
    --->    A.  Yes
            B.  No
```

I've created a dialog that allows the user to dynamically build those questions (add answers, designate the correct one, etc.) inside a form.  Is there anyway to create a model and a Web API that would seamlessly parameter bind that structure on form submission?  I was thinking something crazy like if my form had a table in it that I could somehow bind that to an array in my model?  Probably doesn't work like that but looking for a creative idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model could look something like this

```
public class Question {
    public string Text { get; set;}
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set;}
}

public class Answer {
    public string Label { get; set;}
    public string Text { get; set;}
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set;}
}
```

An api endpoint would take a collection of these to form a test.

```
public class Test {
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Create(Test test) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think my question is more about the form submission than it is about the model structure itself.  I know that Web API has parameter binding.  Basically if the fields in your web form contain name attributes, and the name attribute values match your server side model field names, Web API will automatically map form element values to server side model values for you. That works great for static form fields.  But the answer elements, in this example, are dynamically generated and varied in number. How do I map dynamically created form fields to the model on submission?

Comment: Submit the collection as an array or collection and the ModelBinder will convert them.